# What's the meaning of this code? (Appears at the top of a Windows Form Application page)

Tags: c#, annotations, windows-forms-designer, using-statement, mdf

I'm an A2 level computing student and I'm creating a program for my project which (using c#) takes data from an MDF and displays it in windows form textboxes. Because I'm a totally inexperienced programmer so used an online guide (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s12p7.html) but I now need to explain the code in annotation so was wondering what the following section of code mean:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class
```

I only need a quick explanation for an annotation so any information would be helpful. Thankyou

Comment: How did you tag `using-statement` if you don't know what is it?

Comment: Did you skip the entire first portion of your tutorial? http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s1p3.html

Comment: `10x` more time wasted compared to typing `what is ... c#` (where `...` is what you don't understand) in the google.

Answer (score 2):

In simple terms:

`using` = Include this namespace in this file

`namespace` = A way of identifying / grouping classes into logical groups

`public` = This can be seen by everything in this assembly and any assembly that references it.

`partial` = The class definition can be split over multiple files.

`class` = Well, a class. A class definition starts with the keyword class followed by the class name; and the class body, enclosed by a pair of curly braces.